# Rotating a vector (array)

Tags: c++, vector

I am trying to rotate a vector of elements in C++. What I mean by that is that I have a `vector<point>` I want the last element to become the first.

Example:

> [1,2,3] become [3,1,2] then [2,3,1]

For that I tried to do the following:

```
//Add the last element at index 0
ObjectToRotate.insert(0, ObjectToRotate.at(ObjectToRotate.size()-1));
//Remove Last element
ObjectToRotate.erase(ObjectToRotate.size()-1);
```

but I get this error:

> Error  6   error C2664: 'std::_Vector_iterator<_Myvec> std::vector<*Ty>::insert<cv::Point*<_Tp>&>(std::_Vector_const_iterator<_Myvec>,_Valty)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'int' to 'std::_Vector_const_iterator<_Myvec>'

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There's a [`std::rotate` algorithm](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate) in the standard library:

```
std::rotate(ObjectToRotate.begin(),
            ObjectToRotate.end()-1, // this will be the new first element
            ObjectToRotate.end());
```

Comment: or use a `std::deque` and the `.rotate(1)` member function.

Comment: @CharlesBeattie: `deque` has no `rotate` member function.

Comment: Oops. I have a version that has a rotate (std::deque is slow).

Answer (score 9):

The recommendations to use `std::rotate` are, of course, fully correct;
using an existing function is always the preferred solution when
available.  Never the less, it's worth pointing out why your solution
didn't work.  Containers in the standard library, like `std::vector`,
take position information in the form of iterators, not indexes.  The
idiomatic way of writing your operation would be:

```
v.insert( v.begin(), v.back() );
v.erase( std::prev( v.end() ) );
```

(If you don't have C++11, it's pretty simply to write your own version
of `prev`.  Or in the case of `vector`, you can just write `v.end() -
1`.)

Answer (score 5):

The arguments to `insert` and `erase` are iterators, not indexes:

```
ObjectToRotate.insert(ObjectToRotate.begin(), ObjectToRotate.back());
ObjectToRotate.pop_back();  // or erase(ObjectToRotate.end()-1), if you prefer
```

But it may be more efficient to remove the last element first (after taking a copy), to avoid the possibility of reallocation:

```
auto back = ObjectToRotate.back();
ObjectToRotate.pop_back();
ObjectToRotate.insert(ObjectToRotate.begin(), back);
```

or to use `std::rotate`:

```
std::rotate(ObjectToRotate.begin(), ObjectToRotate.end()-1, ObjectToRotate.end());
```

If you're doing this a lot, then `deque` might be a better choice of container, since that allows efficient insertion and removal at both ends. But, if speed is important, make sure you measure and verify that this really is an improvement; if the sequence isn't very large, then the overhead from the more complicated memory layout might make `deque` slower.

Comment: Re `deque`, one would think so, wouldn't one.  In fact, for containers with few cheaply copyable elements, it turns out that `vector` is still faster.  (Measurements done with `vector<char>` and `deque<char>`, with around ten elements.)  Sort of surprised me, but that's the way it was.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Indeed, I should add the usual disclaimer about optimising prematurely or without measurement.

Comment: In this case... I'd say that given the use, `std::deque` should be the default container---you're inserting or removing at both ends.  It is, in fact, what I'd initially used.  Since my use was in a critical location, I eventually ended up profiling it, and experimenting with other solutions.  With what were, at least to me, somewhat surprising results.  The extra indirections, etc., in a `deque` end up costing more than copying a few PODs.

Answer (score 1):

Use `std::rotate`: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate

Answer (score 1):

[James Kanze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/649665/james-kanze) suggested a fantastic answer of using the following code snippet to rotate individual elements. To rotate *x* amount of items, simply put the below code into a loop.

```
vec.insert( vec.begin(), vec.back() );
vec.erase( std::prev( vec.end() ) );
```

If you CAN use the **standard rotate function**, that'll be your best choice, however. The code below is again rotating *x* number of items, see the [CPP docs about rotate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate), and they even provide code examples showing Left & Right rotation. :)

```
    // simple rotation to the left
    std::rotate(vec.begin(), vec.begin() + x, vec.end());
  
    // simple rotation to the right
    std::rotate(vec.rbegin(), vec.rbegin() + x, vec.rend());
```

Comment: Does this work if you wish to rotate right instead of left, ie, a negative X value?

Comment: Hey @TylerShellberg, I've updated the original post to clarify how to handle left vs right rotations. It's all spelled out in the CPP docs however! https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate

Answer (score 0):

for making [1,2,3] to [2,3,1] here is the code

```
vector<int> Solution::rotateArray(vector<int> &A, int B) {
  vector<int> ret; 
  for (int i = 0; i < A.size(); i++) {
    ret.push_back(A[(i + B) % A.size()]);
  }
  return ret; 
}
```

here A is [1,2,3] and B is 1 to shift 1 position